# Aurelia startup error - Invalid resource path: function Compose

Tags: aurelia

After upgrading my Aurelia Framework in my application via:

> "aurelia-bootstrapper": "^2.3.0"

I'm getting error at the application startup (stack trace at the bottom).

Returning to:

> "aurelia-bootstrapper": "2.2.0"

fixes the error. In release notes for version of Aurelia in question, there is note about additional functionality of `setRoot` method, but nothing that could be breaking change [Aurelia Release Notes - June 2018](https://aurelia.io/blog/2018/06/24/aurelia-release-notes-june-2018).

I just use default:

```
aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
```

This is details stack trace of startup error:

```
vendor-bundle.js:1398 Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid resource path [function Compose(element, container, compositionEngine, viewSlot, viewResources, taskQueue) {


      _initDefineProp(this, 'model', _descriptor, this);

      _initDefineProp(this, 'view', _descriptor2, this);

      _initDefineProp(this, 'viewModel', _descriptor3, this);

      _initDefineProp(this, 'swapOrder', _descriptor4, this);

      this.element = element;
      this.container = container;
      this.compositionEngine = compositionEngine;
      this.viewSlot = viewSlot;
      this.viewResources = viewResources;
      this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
      this.currentController = null;
      this.currentViewModel = null;
      this.changes = Object.create(null);
    }]. Resources must be specified as relative module IDs.
    at FrameworkConfiguration.globalResources (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:69284:17)
    at Object.configure (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:62319:12)
    at http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:69140:36
From previous event:
    at _loadPlugin (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:69138:42)
    at http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:69131:16
From previous event:
    at loadPlugin (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:69130:75)
    at next (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:69392:20)
From previous event:
    at next (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:69392:56)
    at http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:69399:16
From previous event:
    at FrameworkConfiguration.apply (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:69384:44)
    at Aurelia.start (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:69000:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost/scripts/app-bundle.js:5811:33)
    at step (http://localhost/scripts/app-bundle.js:51:23)
    at Object.next (http://localhost/scripts/app-bundle.js:32:53)
    at fulfilled (http://localhost/scripts/app-bundle.js:23:58)
From previous event:
    at step (http://localhost/scripts/app-bundle.js:25:124)
    at http://localhost/scripts/app-bundle.js:26:9
From previous event:
    at __awaiter (http://localhost/scripts/app-bundle.js:22:12)
    at Object.configure (http://localhost/scripts/app-bundle.js:5793:16)
    at http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:70930:29
From previous event:
    at config (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:70925:56)
    at http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:70961:14
From previous event:
    at bootstrap (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:70960:26)
    at http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:70947:9
From previous event:
    at run (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:70942:61)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:70967:37)
    at Object.execCb (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:8724:33)
    at Module.check (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:7911:51)
    at Module.enable (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:8204:22)
    at Object.enable (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:8585:39)
    at Module.<anonymous> (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:8189:33)
    at http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:7162:23
    at each (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:7087:31)
    at Module.enable (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:8141:17)
    at Module.init (http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:7816:26)
    at http://localhost/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:8488:36
printWarning @ vendor-bundle.js:1398
```

Comment: Did you try removing package-lock.json/yarn.lock and node_modules, then redo `npm i` or `yarn`?

Comment: Yes, deleting `yarn.lock` worked.